# Tune performance of postgres query with set operations

Tags: postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL simple insert query using a `FOR loop`. It takes assets of certain account and shifts and pass it to a function whose results is inserted into a table.

I want to optimize this query using set operations instead of `FOR loop`.

Here is the current code.

```
for assetsloop in select * from "Assets" "a" where "a"."AccountId" = _accountid LOOP

          for shiftsloop in select * from temp_table_shifts LOOP

                 insert into temp_table_ignvalues
                 select * from public."GetIgnitionsOrMovements"(
                              shiftsloop.id::uuid,
                              assetsloop.id::uuid,
                               shiftsloop.startDateTime::timestamptz,
                        shiftsloop.stopDateTime::timestamptz,
                              shiftsloop.description::varchar
                       );
          end LOOP;

   end LOOP;
```

I have tried doing the following

```
for assetsloop in select * from "Assets" "a" where "a"."AccountId" = _accountid LOOP

                                            WITH op1 AS (
                                               SELECT * from temp_table_shifts
                                               --RETURNING id, startDateTime, stopDateTime, description
                                            )

                               insert into temp_table_ignvalues
                               select * from public."GetIgnitionsOrMovements"(
                                                                           (select op1.id::uuid from op1),
                                                                            assetsloop.id::uuid,
                                                                            (select op1.startDateTime::timestamptz from op1),
                                                           (select op1.stopDateTime::timestamptz from op1),
                                                                           (select op1.description::varchar from op1)
                                                            );
            end LOOP;
```

But I can error message saying subquery returns more than one row.
Thanks for the help

Comment: there are several subqueries, and we cannot run any part of that code, so don't know how we can assist. Not sure how the second block qualifies as "set operation" as it still sits inside a for loop, it looks like you are doing an unnecessary number of queries.

Comment: I want to send data to `GetIgnitionsOrMovements` function, but doing it without using both `FOR` loops.

Comment: That may be your intention, and it sounds like a good thing to do, but how can we possibly help with so little info? no tables, no data, no fiddle. I could coin toss to choose which of those subqueries is a problem if you like. Should I start with heads or tails?

Comment: Thanks, whichever one. I just need a proper syntax to write that part without the 2 `FOR` loops